# Why is lambda execution deferred in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

Why does `x[i]()` return 9 for any `i`, preceded by this code?

```
x = []
for i in range(1,10):
    x += [lambda: i]
```

Comment: Execution of a function is **always** deferred. You are asking about why looking up `i` is deferred. The answer: closures.

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of why the code does what it does, or an explanation of the language design considerations that lead to Python having that behavior?